# What's the right tape to use on split loom tubing?

Tags: electrical

To wrap split loom tubing, do I use regular electrical tape, or do I use something else?

Comment: I have always used electrical tape.

Comment: Nothing wrong with regular electrical tape. You only need to put it on every so often, not over the entire loom, though. Also, where there are joints. Just enough to hold it together and keep the wiring inside.

Comment: Scotch or 3M brands are the best electrical tape I have used.

Answer (score 1):

Decent electrical tape will work. So not the 10-rolls for a dollar kind you'll find at the big box stores.

If you want a fully waterproof solution, the recommended tape is self-amalgamating tape, but even that has to be covered with PVC tape. (note that I've never used self-amalgamating tape, and the wheels have never fallen of a car I've worked on yet..)

Answer (score 1):

Fleece tape, like Tesa 51608, is the "right" solution. Ordinary electrical tape will surely also work